# iterate folders on my google drive

Tags: c#

i want to iterate folders from google-drive after authentication folder-query line is sending error.the below code is showing the authentication process and then itretating the folder but getting error , please help me , waiting for the reply. I don't want to use the user-credential in coding ,i want to use the client id and client secret so that any one can login to Google drive and iterate folder.

---

### "Execution of request failed: https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/-/folder"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String CLIENT_ID = "74138000159.com";
            String CLIENT_SECRET = "8AE3oJuZomO";
            var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);

            var service = new DriveService(auth);



            DocumentsService service1 = new DocumentsService("MyDocumentsListIntegration-v1");


            // Instantiate a FolderQuery object to retrieve folders.
            FolderQuery query = new FolderQuery();

            // Make a request to the API and get all documents.
           DocumentsFeed feed = service1.Query(query);

            // Iterate through all of the documents returned
            foreach (DocumentEntry entry in feed.Entries)
            {
                // Print the title of this document to the screen
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Title.Text);
            }


        }
          private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
        {

            // Get the auth URL:
            IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { DriveService.Scopes.Drive.GetStringValue() });
            state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
            Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

            // Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
            Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
            Console.Write("  Authorization Code: ");
            string authCode = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
            return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it totally wrong. You must add more code to it as found in https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20 
What you are missing is adding *service1.RequestFactory* setting. Also you don't need to create the *service* object.

Please also note that you are using Google Documents List API version 3.0, which is officially deprecated as of September 14, 2012.

Comment: The entire code is provided in the link specified earlier:
[link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#authorizing_requests). After this line: service.RequestFactory = requestFactory; add the following code too to iterate the folders
DocumentsListQuery query = new DocumentsListQuery();

      // Set the showfolders parameter
      query.ShowFolders = true;

      DocumentsFeed feed = service.Query(query);

      // Iterate through all of the documents returned
      foreach (DocumentEntry entry in feed.Entries)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Title.Text);
      }